# disjoint union and Cartesian product in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I have two set comprehension predicates (uniary) as bellow in Alloy:

```
pred A (o : Object){ .. } 

pred B (o : Object) { ..}
```

I would like to define predicates, one of which is  disjoint union and another one is Cartesian product of A and B.

PS: To define their union and intersection I can define the following predicate:

```
pred Union(o : Object){
    A[o] or B[o]
}

pred Inter(o:Object){
  A[o] and B[o]
}
```

I would like to get similar predicates for Cartesian product and disjoint union.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be conflating the concepts of predicates and the concepts of sets.  You have good company (Frege, for one), but it turns out to be dangerous.

The expressions `o in A[o]` and `o in B[o]` should raise a type error, since if A and B are predicates, then the expressions `A[o]` and `B[o]` should evaluate to true or false, and not to sets of which o could conceivably be a member.

If you want a predicate U which is true of an object when either A or B or both are true for that object, then you want something like

```
pred U[o : Object] { A[o] or B[o] }
```

And if you want an exclusive disjunction -- I assume that this is what you mean when you speak of a disjoint union -- then

```
pred X[o : Object] { (A[o] and not B[o]) or (B[o] and not A[o]) }
```

If you want the sets for which A, B, and X are true, then you want to write

```
{ o : Object | A[o] } 
{ o : Object | B[o] } 
{ o : Object | X[o] }
```

The third of these can of course be written

```
{ o : Object | (A[o] and not B[o]) or (B[o] and not A[o]) }
```

The set comprehension notation (again, I encourage you to read the relevant documentation) can also handle sets of tuples; the Cartesian product of the sets of objects satisfying A and B would be written this way:

```
{ a, b : Object | A[a] and B[b] }
```

Comment: I corrected the Union and Inter bodies. There is a reason I treated sets as unary predicates in my application. What about disjoint union of tow sets and cartesian product? how can I write them as predicates?

Comment: @qartal, if by 'disjoint union' you mean something other than the exclusive disjunction described in the answer, then you probably need to define what you mean.  Cartesian products are also expressible using comprehensions; I repeat my recommendation that you read about comprehensions in the documentation.

Comment: by disjoint union I mean the operation described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union). 
would you please let me know which document you mean to take a look for the cartesian product? you mean the alloy book (software abstraction)?

Comment: I wasn't intending to suggest a specific passage for you to read; *Software Abstractions* does discuss comprehensions, and I suspect the Alloy tutorial and reference material on the Web does, too.  If, having read it and considered the examples of comprehensions given here, you cannot figure out how to express disjoint union, I will be very surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to what I was looking for:

cartesian product of A and B are defined as A * B = {(a,b) | a in A and b in B}. So putting it in Alloy syntax with set comprehension expression would be as follows:

```
pred ACartesB(o1:Object, o2: Object){
    A[o1] and B[o2]
}
```

disjoint union of A and B are defined as A+B= {(a,1) union (b,2) | a in A and b in B}. 1 and 2 are indexes to distinguish the same elements of A and B in A+B. So putting it in alloy context would be as the following:

```
pred AdisjUnionB(o:Object, i: Int){
    (A[o] and i=1) or (B[o] and i=2)
}
```

PS:
we assume that we have `sig Object {}` in our signature.